# Soundcloud: Stratus player continue to play across pages?

Tags: soundcloud

I'm confused about whether the Stratus player for SoundCloud can play continuously between pages, or at least pick up the track where it was.

SoundCloud describes the STratus player as follows...  "A bunch of you told us that the only SoundCloud player that was missing was one that would float on the top or bottom of a site **and continue to play as you switch pages, we feel like we've solved that with our Stratus player!"** (http://soundcloud.com/101/stratus)

But on the Stratus2 page it says "Can I keep Stratus playing even when the page reloads?
Not currently." (http://stratus.sc/)

Is there some way to have SoundCloud play continuously between pages, or at least pick up the track where it was?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you can achieve this with the [HTML5 History API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html).

> The HTML5 history API is a standardized way to manipulate the browser
>   history via script. Part of this API — navigating the history — has
>   been available in previous versions of HTML. The new parts in HTML5
>   include a way to add entries to the browser history, to visibly change
>   the URL in the browser location bar (without triggering a page
>   refresh), and an event that fires when those entries are removed from
>   the stack by the user pressing the browser’s back button. This means
>   that the URL in the browser location bar can continue to do its job as
>   a unique identifier for the current resource, even in script-heavy
>   applications that don’t ever perform a full page refresh.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I keep Stratus playing even when the page reloads?
>
> Not currently. Your site would need to be built so that it doesn't
>   reload rather than the player. However, we do provide a popup function
>   that users can click to enjoy your tunes while browsing your site.

I'm guessing that the line about changing pages refers to possibility of popping the player out and navigating the website. You could also build your website with something like [pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) and then keep stratus in the “footer” so navigating your website will only update the contents.

I hope this helps.